# Sharepoint online lookup field hyperlinks not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

We are using SharePoint Online and we have noticed the hyperlinks on lookup fields in a list are not working.

These are the links that appear in the list view when you have a lookup field that points to another list, this is an example of the url:

```
https://sharepointsite.sharepoint.com/u002f/u002fsharepointsite.sharepoint.com/u002fsites/u002ftest-site/u002f_layouts/u002f15/u002flistform.aspx?PageType=4\u0026ListId={8715c5cd-2db4-4dec-a625-1a04e68e7910}&ID=1&RootFolder=*&IsDlg=1
```

If you remove the u002f etc. and generally clean up the URL, it works fine.

This has happened to all our sites in every list where we have a lookup field that points to another list/field.

This occurs in IE 11 and the latest version of Edge and Firefox

I am not sure what caused this to happen?

Comment: I've noticed the links are fine if you use the "new experience" for the document library, this problem only occurs with the classic experience

Comment: It looks like it's being Unicode escaped for some reason.  You might be able to use JavaScript to fix it.

Comment: Is it the same issue described here? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242499/getting-404-not-found-when-clicking-on-lookup-link

Comment: Yes Denis that's the same issue, at least I know it's not specific to our site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked two SharePoint online tenants. One with early releases enabled and the other without it.

Looks like lookups in tenants with the latest updates are broken now. When we click on them in the Classic Experience the URL is incorrectly formatted which gives us a 404 Error.

Comment: I've just checked and it works fine now, so I'm guessing Microsoft fixed it.