# Getting "404 NOT FOUND" when clicking on lookup link

Tags: list, lookup-column, 404

In the past, when clicking on a lookup item on a list, it would show a popup with the data of that lookup item, but now I get a "404 NOT FOUND". I tried creating a new list and adding a lookup from various lists, I still get this no matter what.

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Is this SharePoint Online? Looks like you are not alone: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242492/sharepoint-online-lookup-field-hyperlinks-not-working

Comment: Looks like this has now been fixed by Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

I've checked two SharePoint online tenants. One with early releases enabled and the other without it.

Looks like lookups in tenants with the latest updates are broken now. When we click on them in the Classic Experience the URL is incorrectly formatted which gives us a 404 Error.

Comment: How would you suggest raising this with UserVoice or Microsoft?

Comment: Office 365 has support section in the administration panel. This support is free and works well. They respond or call you back quickly.

Comment: I've contacted support about this yesterday, they called back very quickly but the agent wanted to connect to my machine remotely but our firewall blocks it. They are going to ring back again later today, hopefully this issue will get through to the right people eventually

Comment: Hi guys, Any progress here?